Encrypt Query Parameter in Flutter and decrypt in PHP to get Data
The IV and the key are up here.

 // Verschlüsselt den Job-Parameter
  String encryptJob(String job) {
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(job, iv: iv);
    return encrypted.base64; // Base64-String des verschlüsselten Textes
  }

  String encryptMessage (String message){
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(message, iv:iv);
    return encrypted.base64;
  }

Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final message = '&function=';

    // Verschlüsselung des Job-Parameters
    final encryptedJob1 = encryptJob('job=$job1');
    final encryptedJob2 = encryptJob('job=$job2');
    final encryptedJob3 = encryptJob('job=$job3');
    final encryptedJob4 = encryptJob('job=$job4');


    //IV und verschlüsselte Daten für die URL korrekt kodieren
    final encodedIV = Uri.encodeComponent(iv.base64);
    final encodedJob1 = Uri.encodeComponent(encryptedJob1);
    final encodedJob2 = Uri.encodeComponent(encryptedJob2);
    final encodedJob3 = Uri.encodeComponent(encryptedJob3);
    final encodedJob4 = Uri.encodeComponent(encryptedJob4);
    final encryptedMessage = encryptMessage('$message$encodedJob4');

    // Jetzt den IV korrekt in Base64 umwandeln und in die URL einfügen
    final webServiceURl = 'http://localhost/get_encrypt_request.php?iv=$encodedIV$message$encodedJob4';
    final url = Uri.parse(webServiceURl);
    final response = await http.get(url);

    print('$url\n');
    print(response.body);

    setState(() {
      data = response.body;
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Erfolgreiche Antwort');
    } else {
      print('Fehler beim Abrufen der Daten: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

My Task is to encrypt the queryParamters that no plaintext can be seen affter the ?.
I can encrypt my job but not my queryparameter in that case the message per se.
And after that the queryparameter must than be decrypt in php and send me the data from the job.
// Empfange den IV und die verschlüsselten Daten
$iv = isset($_GET['iv']) ? $_GET['iv'] : '';
$data = isset($_GET['function']) ? $_GET['function'] : '';

  final encryptedMessage = encryptMessage('$message$encodedJob4');


In this line you can see that i have tried to put the message with the job but than for the job it is a "double encryption" and that is indeed not that sence.
    final webServiceURl = 'http://localhost/get_encrypt_request.php?iv=$encodedIV$encryptedMessage';


When i change the queryparameters to this for sure it doesn't work.

Why exactly do you need to encrypt a specific value like this? If you don't want people to see the data which is being sent, then: 1) You should use HTTPS as the transmission protocol, so that the entire message is encrypted can't be intercepted and 2) if you're worried about the parameter appearing in logs of the URLs etc, then turn the request into a POST and put the data in the request body. This is a lot less hassle than encrypting individual parameters.

"I can encrypt my job but not my queryparameter in that case the message per se." - what actually is the "message" you need to transport here? Are you talking about a parameter by the name function, and with the value job=$job4, in this case? ?iv=$encodedIV$message$encodedJob4 should result in ?iv=[something encoded]&function=[something encoded], yes? So then where is the actual problem now? $_GET['function'] should give you access to that second encoded value.

There should no longer be any plain text in the URL. That is the case

That's doesn't answer the point about why you need to do that. What problem are you trying to solve by doing that? What is the need to hide the parameter value. What would go wrong if it's not hidden? As I said in my first comment, if you simply want privacy while the data is in transit there are simpler ways to achieve that, compared to the overhead of encrypting and decrypting each paramter value individually. This smells like an XY problem (i.e. asking how to implement the wrong solution) - hence why we're asking you to explain what the overall rationale for this feature is.

OK. I'm here in my internship semester and my job is to encrypt the communication between the client (Flutter) and the server (PHP). The server then sends me the data required for the job.

HTTPS is the standard way to encrypt communication between the client and the server when using HTTP web requests. That encrypts the entire message from end to end, not just one little part of it. Nobody can intercept and read anything within it. All you have to do is make sure the webserver has a valid SSL certificate on it (for localhost testing, a self-signed certificate is sufficient)  and your flutter application can make a request to (for example) https://localhost/somescript.php. The encryption is then taken care of automatically for you.

Ok. Thank you i think that helps me.
